How do Matplotlib and TeX communicate?
This follows a recent post which got a few views and no reply at all. I have a system with Windows 11, Python 3.10.8 and Matplotlib 3.9.2 and MiKTeX 24.0. Until a couple of weeks ago, I was able to plot nice charts like this one:

But not any more. Out of the blue, TeX stopped working. Now I get a strange error that seems to have nothing to do with a Windows system (after a lot of omitted lines):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm'

In this case, I was trying to use the Computer Modern Roman font.
The point is: this is a Windows system, while "/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/..." is clearly a Linux path. How are those things related?
My questions are, therefore:
(1) Where from does Matplotlib fetch the TeX-style fonts? As I said, I have MiKTeX installed.
(2) Is there a command that can tell me what is Matplotlib trying to do?
(3) Could I change the Matplotlib configuration file to point to the TeX fonts?
Don't get me wrong, though. A simple script like this one works nicely:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-2.0*np.pi, 2.0*np.pi, 200)

plt.figure(1)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("f(x)")
plt.plot(x, np.cos(x), 'b.')
plt.show()

it's when I try to use TeX rendering that I get that error message and a blank plotting window.
Any help will be much appreciated. I really don't know what to do. I have uninstalled and reinstalled everything more than once - to no avail.
Thanks.

Asking the same question over and over again won't increase your chances of getting an answer. Please don't do this. If you believe you found a bug in any of the projects you mention, you should report it there, not here.

@Friedrich
Patronizing doesn't help either. This post has a little more detail than the previous one, and I tried a few fixes between the two. Besides, nobody would have noticed that I "reposted" my question if I hadn't mentioned that myself. Believe me, I hate posting here - and because of people with your attitude. SO's always my last resort. Unfortunately, Matplotlib has a poor support and no community forum (e.g. a Google Group) where I could send specific problems like this - and if you happen to know one, please be really helpful and let me know.

"nobody would have noticed that I "reposted" my question if I hadn't mentioned that myself." - so if you steal something and nobody notices, it's not stealing? "I hate posting here" - I believe this is because your goals ("give me my answer, fast!") are at odds with the goals of this site ("build a curated repository of every programming related problem"). From SO's viewpoint, the dupe is waste. If you found out more details, edit your original question. It will be bumped to the front page, increasing its visibility.

A quick internet search finds matplotlib's issue tracker. There's also links to discourse, a mailing list, etc. in its README.

FWIW this question might do better on Matplotlib’s discourse, since more of Matplotlib’s maintainers look there, and it seems to be a question about the internals.  OTOH it likely will not get a reply as quickly since there are fewer people doing the answering than there are here.

That doesn't seem to be a matplotlib issue, that's the point. As I hinted (perhaps I should've been totally clear about that - my bad), nothing changed between the states of full TeX operability and non-operability. That is, nothing ordinary that I would recall (version updates, Python interpreter upgrade, etc). It stopped working overnight, period. Frankly, this seems so strange and specific that I'm hopeless about an answer.

I fixed my Matplotlib installation. How? Well, not too sure how. But it dawned on me that my system might have more than one Matplotlib configuration file, matplotlibrc, from previous installations in several other places. Indeed, a global search showed that I had three (3) matplotlibrc files. One of them was the "official" one, because it was on the folder where it was expected to be.
The second one was a remnant of an old, now uninstalled, Cygwin-X environment. I uninstalled those Matplotlib leftovers, and a second global search showed that my system was clean of this configuration file and all Cygwin-X Matplotlib residues. But that didn't fix anything. I was still getting the same error.
The third matplotlibrc file was created by a wxMaxima/Maxima, a CAS package I had recently installed. Curiously, this config file had a size of around 22 KB, which is half the size of a regular matplotlibrc file (44 KB). In this case, I wiped the whole thing out. I uninstalled the CAS completely. That got me rid of the config file. Yet the problem persisted.
Then I installed Texstudio, to see if Matplotlib could somehow use the fonts (?) from its library (?). Again, nothing happened.
Out of despair, I decided to install TeX Live, of which I had never heard before or had ever installed on my system. After 21 hours (yes, almost a whole day!) of downloads, the installation began and, shortly before its completion, the nicely TeX-decorated charts were back. No system boot required. This made me very happy. I have hundreds of scripts using LaTeX, neat applications that took me days of work to put together - and that all of a sudden became completely useless.
It seems that Matplotlib liked Tex Live. But why was it working before as it always did, when there was no Tex Live at all on my machine? Why did it stop working? I think I will never know.

I have always appreciated persistence and tenacity

Foe what is worth, TeX Live is the TeX distribution of choice for Unix-y systems
